# @PreAuthorize and intercept-url priority

Tags: spring-security, spring-annotations

I have

```
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
```

in the Spring Security context configuration file and

```
@PreAuthorize("permitAll")
@RequestMapping("/public")
public String aMethod() {
    // ...
}
```

in a controller.

What I want is that all the URLs to require authentication except `public`. Is this possible?

Comment: That will not work. What you have defined `/**/*` global pattern. Means everything should have `ROLE_USER` and then you are trying for `/public` which is confusing with `/**`. Why don't you define two patterns.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to have all the URLs secured unless specified otherwise in a @PreAuthorize annotation. How should I define those two pattern to achieve this?

Comment: Once you define something at XML global path level then it would not even reach @PreAuthorize("permitAll") method level. I would recommend dividing it. Something like - ` <intercept-url pattern="/allow/**" access="permitAll" /> and <intercept-url pattern="/restrict/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />``.

Comment: Verified and it does not work and should not work.

Comment: So, intercept-url in XML takes precedence over annotations. Please put this as an answer and I'll accept it.
But is it possible to define a default behavior if an URL is not matched by any intercept-url or any @PreAuthorize annotation?

Comment: Actually it makes sense, because intercept-url is at URL level and annotations are at method level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<intercept-url>` in XML takes precedence over annotations. `<intercept-url>` works at URL level and annotations at method level.

If you are going to use `spring security` and `spring` `<form-login />` then the approach below would serve you better.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/public/**"
                   access="permitAll" />

<intercept-url pattern="/restricted/**"
                   access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SOME')


@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SOME')")
@RequestMapping("/restricted/aMethod")
public String aMethod() {
    // ...
}
```

Anything under `restricted` can be accessed by three different roles. But specific path `restricted/aMethod` can be accessed by `@PreAuthorize("ROLE_ADMIN")` and `@PreAuthorize("ROLE_SOME")` but NOT by `@PreAuthorize("ROLE_USER")`. By default all three roles can access but when you mark some path with `@PreAuthorize("ROLE_ADMIN")` then user with `ROLE_ADMIN` can access that path.

If you think about it, `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SOME')")` act as narrowed or filtered access from a large set of `ROLES` to single(or set of roles) `ROLE`.

As you would notice, none of `/restricted` paths are accessible by `permitAll`. Its preferred to have `/static/*.css` and others under `permitAll`.

HTH